# Flume - Hdfs sink output directory permission

Tags: permissions, flume

Is it possible to specify the permission of the output direcory of an hdfs sink in Flume?

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible.

Refer below URL.
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#system-requirements